Azure monitor open telemetry python package raising exception when python app deployed on Azure
I have a Python web application built with Plotly Dash and deployed on Azure App Service using Python 3.12. As Azure App Service has not yet enabled Python 3.12 version to have application insight enabled, I have utilized the package:
azure-monitor-opentelemetry==1.6.2

within my application to log exceptions into my application insight resource.
However, as I deploy my web application on Azure App Service, and when someone is accessing the web app, my application logs the following exception onto the application insight:
Failed to derive Resource from Tracer Provider: 'ProxyTracerProvider' object has no attribute 'resource'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/8dcd22e385c2da5/antenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/azure/monitor/opentelemetry/exporter/export/trace/_exporter.py", line 91, in export
    resource = tracer_provider.resource # type: ignore

AttributeError: 'ProxyTracerProvider' object has no attribute 'resource'
I have implemented the azure-monitor-opentelemetry in my application simply as following:
appopentelemetry.py:
from azure.monitor.opentelemetry import configure_azure_monitor
from models.environmentmanager.environmentmanager import EnvironmentManager


def azure_monitoring_open_telemetry():
    environment_manager = EnvironmentManager()
    connection_string = environment_manager.get_connection_string() # The app insight connection string 

    return configure_azure_monitor(
        connection_string=connection_string,
        enable_live_metrics=True,
    )

and in my app.py:
...imports...

environment_manager = EnvironmentManager()

# This should be executed if the environment is not local, this is set in .env if ran locally
# and set in environment variables of the app service on Azure when deployed
if not environment_manager.get_is_local():
    from functions.app.appopentelemetry import azure_monitoring_open_telemetry
    azure_monitoring_open_telemetry()

...

app = Dash(__name__, use_pages=True, external_stylesheets=stylesheets)

...
app.layout = dmc.MantineProvider(...)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8000)

Can I know what I am doing wrong?

Version 1.6.2 also upgrades azure-monitor-opentelemetry-exporter to "1.0.0b29" and it has the braking changes. Just downgrade to azure-monitor-opentelemetry-exporter = "1.0.0b28" and maybe to azure-monitor-opentelemetry = "1.6.1". It will solve the issue for now.
In general, I think that config should be done differntly rather then using configure_azure_monitor but it is not that clear from the documentation. Try to read here https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/python/getting-started/

Hi @Andrii, thanks for the reply. I have downgraded my azure-monitor-opentelemetry to "1.6.0" but it is still occurring for the issue. Furthermore, I am using Python version 3.12 as my Azure App Service (web app) runtime stack. Could the runtime stack Python 3.12 be the issue here?

Just fix the azure-monitor-opentelemetry-exporter version to "1.0.0b28" in requirements file and the issue will be solved

the issue was fixed in the package and azure-monitor-opentelemetry-exporter = "1.0.0b30" doesn't raise exception after configure_azure_monitor call

Fixed the issue thanks to @Andrii and @Sirra. Turns out one of azure-monitor-opentelemetry==1.6.2 dependencies packages which is the azure-monitor-opentelemetry-exporter was automatically installing the '1.0.0b29' version, so in my requirements.txt file I stated the following:
azure-monitor-opentelemetry==1.6.1 
azure-monitor-opentelemetry-exporter==1.0.0b28

And this has fixed the issue.

In addition to @Andrii's  answer ,

Update your packages by running the below command. You can refer this doc for compatibility information.

pip install dash azure-monitor-opentelemetry==1.6.2 opentelemetry-sdk opentelemetry-exporter-otlp


As the error message says'ProxyTracerProvider' object has no attribute 'resource'  you can create and configure your own Trace provider.
You can refer this doc for tracebacks in python.

This is my appopentelemetry .py
from azure.monitor.opentelemetry import configure_azure_monitor
from opentelemetry.sdk.resources import Resource
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import TracerProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import BatchSpanProcessor
from opentelemetry.exporter.otlp.proto.grpc.trace_exporter import OTLPSpanExporter
from models.environmentmanager.environmentmanager import EnvironmentManager

def azure_monitoring_open_telemetry():
    
    environment_manager = EnvironmentManager()
    connection_string = environment_manager.get_connection_string()

    resource = Resource(attributes={"service.name": "your-app-name"})
    tracer_provider = TracerProvider(resource=resource)
    span_processor = BatchSpanProcessor(OTLPSpanExporter())  tracer_provider.add_span_processor(span_processor)
    
    configure_azure_monitor(
        connection_string=connection_string,
        tracer_provider=tracer_provider,
        enable_live_metrics=True,
    )
    return tracer_provider


While creating the Azure App Service, select Python 3.10 or Python 3.11, These versions are recommended for better compatibility with most libraries and services.
refer this doc  for better understanding.

Here's the output


Hi @Sirra, thanks for the reply. My Azure App Service is currently running on Python 3.12  runtime stack. Could this be the reason why this issue is coming? I will also try out that code you provided, thanks for that! Lastly, to use the code would you recommend using azure-monitor-opentelemetry version "1.3.2" or "1.3.0"? Cheers

@JasonSusanto Yes, the issue may be due to using Python 3.12 on your Azure App Service, as azure-monitor-opentelemetry and some dependencies might not fully support this version yet.

If possible, try changing your runtime stack to Python 3.11, as it's more compatible with azure-monitor-opentelemetry and should help avoid these errors.

Hi @Sirra, thanks for that, I have considered that change to Python 3.11 but I have several packages depending on Python 3.12, hence, I am sticking with Python 3.12 and implementing the fix that Andrii has suggested. Much thanks for this though!

A new version of the exporter that has a fix for this issue is released: https://pypi.org/project/azure-monitor-opentelemetry-exporter/1.0.0b30/
